# Какие знаки препинания нужны между двумя частями цитаты, нужны ли кавычки после первой части и перед второй?

Tags: пунктуация

«Если наши аборигены в самом деле происходят от колен Израиля», - писал Смит, – «американские христиане справедливо могут считать, что здесь, в их наследии есть нечто великое: они могут сыграть главную роль в деле возвращения этих заблудших овец дома Израилева»[6].

Answer (score 1):

124. КАВЫЧКИ ПРИ ЦИТАТАХ
125. Цитаты заключаются в кавычки. Если цитата оформляется как прямая речь, т. е. сопровождается словами автора, приводящего ее, то применяются соответствующие правила пунктуации (см. § 119-122):

Белинский писал: «Создаёт человека природа, но развивает и образует его общество».

«Двенадцать миллионов людей вне закона!.. Ужас!..» — писал в своём дневнике Герцен, имея в виду крепостных крестьян в тoгдaшнeй России.

Ваш случай.

**«Стало быть, для того чтобы понять историю искусства и литературы той или другой страны, — указывает Г. В. Плеханов, — надо изучить историю тех изменений, которые произошли в положении её жителей».**

Источник: http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/rules-rosental/articles/124-kavychki-pri-citatah.htm